# Key binding for Smerge

Tags: key-bindings, smerge

I'm trying to change the key bindings to all the `smerge` commands. I added :

```
(setq smerge-command-prefix "\C-c v")
```

to my Emacs config. `M-x customize smerge` confirms that the Smerge Command Prefix is `^C v` but all my `smerge` commands still starts with `C-c ^`.

I also tried

```
(setq smerge-command-prefix (kbd "C-c v"))
```

but same result.

Comment: Came here looking for how to customize smerge keybindings. `M-x customize smerge` pointed me to the answer: `M-x customize-variable RET smerge-command-prefix`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this will take effect if you restart Emacs.

Alternatively, `M-x load-library RET smerge RET` will process it.  (In which case the old prefix will also remain active, until you restart.)

Comment: I've tried restarting my emacs daemon multiple times but still no effects. I just tried `load-library` also but still nothing. Thanks though.

Comment: It worked for me after `(setq smerge-command-prefix (kbd "C-c v"))` in Emacs 26.1.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I tried it with `emacs -Q` and it works perfectly. After spending some time investigating the problem in my emacs config, I found the source of the problem to be `magit-filenotify.el` (https://github.com/ruediger/magit-filenotify). I'm not sure yet why it breaks this keybinding.

Answer (score 2):

`smerge-command-prefix` is used by `smerge.el` when the `smerge.el` file is loaded.  So you need to perform your `setq` before `smerge.el` is loaded.  My crystal ball tells me that you likely have something in your `.emacs` which causes smerge to be loaded before that `setq`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, unfortunately, I don't think this is the problem as disabling `magit-filenotify.el` solves the issue (As explain to @phils) but `smerge.el` isn't called by this file. I still have to take the time to understand why.

Comment: magit-filenotify.el requires `magit` which requires `magit-diff` which requires `smerge-mode`